# What is "IT-Fachkräftezulage" in German TVÖD and who is eligible for it?

Tags: germany

I have found a form for applying for an IT-Fachkräftezulage but have no idea whether I'm eligible.

What is this actually?

Comment: Needs more details or clarity? How can a question be more straightforward than asking "What is this"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compensation when working for the German state is strongly regulated. Salaries according to the regulations are not competitive for IT specialists.

The IT-Fachkräftezulage is a regulatory exception to offer IT specialists working for the government a higher salary.

You are eligible if you are an IT Specialist applying for a government job and the position you are applying for is in a specific salary range. The salary range is specified in German as *"Entgeltgruppen 9a bis 15 TVöD oder  Entgeltgruppen 9 bis 15 TV-V"*.